# Android Proguard errors on compile

Tags: android, proguard

I'm using proguard for the first time, and when I compiled the app I received the following error stack:

```
Note: there were 1 duplicate class definitions.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadableDateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateMidnightDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$DateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$JodaDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$JodaDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$JodaDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$JodaDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaDeserializers$LocalDateTimeDeserializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$DateMidnightSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight$Property
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$DateMidnightSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$DateMidnightSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight$Property
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$DateMidnightSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateMidnight
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$DateTimeSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.DateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$JodaSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$JodaSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$JodaSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$JodaSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadablePartial
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$JodaSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.ReadableInstant
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate$Property
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate$Property
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDate
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateTimeSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime$Property
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateTimeSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateTimeSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime$Property
Warning:org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers$LocalDateTimeSerializer: can't find referenced class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
Warning:there were 99 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
:app:proguardDebug FAILED
```

I tried with both the basic changes to proguard-rules.txt and with everything in that file commented out and get the same result, so the contents of that (or lack thereof) don't seem to have any bearing on this error being thrown.

As you can see, there isn't anything pointing to what exactly is duplicate. Also, the warning lines below the message about duplication reference a package I don't use anywhere in my app.

I've tried searching for this problem and attempted to add some lines such as

`-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }`

which someone suggested but that didn't do the trick.

Here is something in the build.gradle file for my app which is raising a flag:

`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'`

I have a file proguard-rules.txt in the root folder of my app (the same directory as my build.gradle file), but I don't have a proguard-android.txt file there, or anywhere else I could find for that matter. Could that be a cause?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't have any errors, these are warnings which, according to what the `log` says,

```
If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
     the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
```

can be suppressed with the following line in the *ProGuard config*:

```
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Add on your PROGuard file:

```
-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.**
-keep class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.** { *; }
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your proguard config:

```
-keep class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.** { *; }
-keep class org.joda.time.** { *; }
```

Comment: Dang, that didn't work. I'm adding my build.gradle file to the question, I see something there that raises a flag for me.